# Craft3: 1 Click update - broken site

Tags: craft3, error, updates, auto-updates

Tried the 1 Click Update and it bombed.

on domain.com/admin/utlities/updates url I get

```
Twig Runtime Error – Twig_Error_Runtime
Variable "CraftPersonal" does not exist.
1. in /vendor/craftcms/cms/src/templates/_layouts/basecp.html
```

And then on the domain.com/admin/dashboard url:

```
Twig Runtime Error – Twig_Error_Runtime
Variable "CraftClient" does not exist.
1. in /vendor/craftcms/cms/src/templates/_components/widgets/RecentEntries/body.html
```

The CP is now unusuable

Comment: This is a bug which is being addressed by Pixel & Tonic.

Comment: OK cool, looks like an update may have been released, but no docs, instructions on how to complete an unfinished update when the CP is broke..

Comment: Run `composer update`, it should bring you up to the latest version.

Comment: We've just hit this issue also and running composer update didn't resolve it. What we proceeded to do is to go to https://github.com/craftcms/cms and download the repo as a zip file. We then removed the src folder on the server and replaced it with this freshly downloaded version. After making this change we could get back in and all is well again in our craft3 install. We had a large number of updates to run as we were updating from RC8 to 3.0.1. I hope this helps anyone else who hits this issue and can't resolve it through composer.